# Error 404 even though routes exist - AWS, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just made a new instance on AWS EC2. I have an existing laravel project, pushed it on github and installed it on my new instance. Also installed composer, php, mysql, apache. And when I hit the `public` url, laravel redirects me to `public/auth/login`. On my localhost everything is fine, but here it givesme an error 404 - `Not Found The requested URL /auth/login was not found on this server.`. I have installed before my laravel projects in AWS but never experienced such an error. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: So you mean your url is `http://yourdomain.com/public`? If that's the case, you need to change the HTTP server's Document Root to point to the `public` directory of your application. Your URL paths should not contain `public` within them.

Comment: I pointed it right in the public directory and still gives me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything was from the `.htaccess` file. I added `AllowOverride All` and everything is ok now!

Comment: Instead of modifying the .htaccess file on the public folder, you can just update your virtual host configuration file (e.g. /etc/apache2/site-available/00-default.conf)

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. How does your .htaccess file look? Where did you add AllowOverride All?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using apache server then do the following

1. Go to your apache2.conf file,
   For example in ubuntu the path is
   `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Paste the following code by making suitable modifiction

```
<Directory /var/www/the_root_of_your_laravel_project_where_index.php_exists/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using default Amazon Linux, you can edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and set `DocumentRoot "<your path to your app>/public"` then restart Apache with `sudo service httpd restart`.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu, but I already did this yesterday. And the problem remained unsolved. So what I did: 
 `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`
`sudo nano 000-default.conf` -> chaged it to: `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/BlueDrive_1/drive/public`